# Vercel build TypeError: _.map is not a function

Tags: typescript, next.js, typeerror, server-side-rendering, vercel

I am encountering a typeError when I attempt to deploy my next.js application on vercel

```
TypeError: items.map is not a function
at SearchResults (/vercel/path0/.next/server/app/exercises/page.js:568:29)
at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)

Error occurred prerendering page "/exercises". Read more: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/prerender-error
TypeError: items.map is not a function
at SearchResults (/vercel/path0/.next/server/app/exercises/page.js:568:29)
at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
```

I have a component SearchResults that is supposed to render a list of exercise items fetched using the getAll function.

```
import React from "react";
import getAll from "@/lib/getAll";
import ResultItem from "./ResultItem";
import { Exercise } from "@prisma/client";

export default async function SearchResults() {
  const items: Exercise[] = await getAll();
  return (
<div>
  <div>
    {items.map((item: Exercise) => {
      return (
        <ResultItem
          key={item.id}
          id={item.id}
          title={item.name}
          image={item.image}
        />
      );
    })}
  </div>
</div>
```

);
}

```
export default async function getAll() {
  const res = await fetch(`${process.env.CLIENT_URL}/api/exercises`);
  if (!res.ok) return new Error("Failed to fetch data");
  return res.json();
}
```

I tested the component locally everything works fine. And even when building the project locally using 'next build' command, no errors or warnings are shown. I'd appreciate any insights or suggestions on how to resolve this error. Thank you.

What I tried:
I tried creating a typescript interface instead of using prisma client types. Hard coding the values in the items variable seemed to work but thats not what i'm looking for.

What I expect to happen:
I expect the build process to finish successfully.

What accually resulted:
TypeError: items.map is not a function

Comment: You can put nullable check like - item?.map OR {items && items.map … }

Answer (score 0):

`process.env.CLIENT_URL` is most likely `undefined` on your Vercel environment. Double check its value in the Vercel projet settings. Also, variables not prefixed with `NEXT_CLIENT_` do not get exposed on the client side, which I believe is what you are using right now.
In the end, `items` has no value leading to `items.map is not a function`, you might want to add a check for this as well.

I invite you to have a read [about environment variables with NextJs](https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/building-your-application/configuring/environment-variables#bundling-environment-variables-for-the-browser).